# Do a GET request with parameters on iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, asihttprequest

I'm doing an app which retrieves user info, and it does that using a GET request, but I don't know how could I make one. Already tried ASIHTTPRequest with this code:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://forrst.com/api/v2/users/info"];
    // Now, set up the post data:
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];

    [request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"id"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];

    // Initiate the WebService request
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

But I get this response from forrst:

```
2011-06-05 16:59:32.189 Forrsty[4335:207] {"resp":{"error":"you must pass either id or username"},"stat":"fail","in":0.0557,"authed":false,"authed_as":false,"env":"prod"}
```

Which I understand I'm not doing the GET request ok, so how I would do it? Thanks :)

Comment: The name of the method, setPostValue, should be all the info you need. It's setting a *post* value, not a get value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Get Parameter ?

So why don't you try "http://forrst.com/api/v2/users/info?id=1" ?

```
[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://forrst.com/api/v2/users/info?id=%d", 1 ];
```

By the way, take a look at this librayry : http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Good luck !

Comment: Nice one! It worked, and BTW I'm using ASIHTTPRequest, but thanks again, will mark as correct answer when StackOverflow allows me to do it ;)

Comment: Yes, saw it too late you were using too. Little bit tired ! ^^ You should be able to mark it aven with your rank, nop ? strange.

Comment: yeah but it makes me unable to mark it as a correct answer until 2 mins :)